# How to get the header content from *fasthttp.Request of Golang?

Tags: go, fasthttp

> As the title says , is there an api for that?

```
*fasthttp.Request.Header.key
```

> When I call the method with POSTMAN , I can't get the header content key as the above code . Why

Answer (score 4):

It may surprise you to learn that fasthttp doesn't store request header values as an exported `map[string]string`, but as an unexported `[]byte` which it stores indexes into. This apparently is one of its performance optimizations.

You can get a request header value with [`Peek()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestHeader.Peek).

```
v := ctx.Request.Header.Peek("User-Agent")
```

Note that this function returns a byte slice, so you'll probably have to convert it to a `string`.

```
sv := string(v)
```

Comment: At first, I used this method to obtain, and the result was not obtained.